# How to insert image into a footer of MS Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a trouble.

I make a project where I need to change every page of a MS word document by inserting image into the bottom of the page. I can insert image into a footer using `Spire.DOC` but the image is the same for every page. So the problem is to insert different image on every page. Can anyone help me how it can be implemented? Thank you!

Example, how to use Spire.DOC for inserting image

```
//Insert an image into footer paragraph
Paragraph footer = footer.AddParagraph();
DocPicture image = footer.AppendPicture(Image.FromFile("some_image.jpg");

//The alignment of the footer picture
image.TextWrappingStyle = TextWrappingStyle.Behind;
image.HorizontalOrigin = HorizontalOrigin.Page;
image.HorizontalAlignment = ShapeHorizontalAlignment.Center;
image.VerticalOrigin = VerticalOrigin.Page;
image.VerticalAlignment = ShapeVerticalAlignment.Bottom;

//Set the text of the footer
TextRange text = footer.AppendText("some_document.Doc";
text.CharacterFormat.FontName = "Arial";
text.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 11;
text.CharacterFormat.Italic = false;
footer.Format.HorizontalAlignment = Spire.Doc.Documents.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

//Add a border of the footer
footer.Format.Borders.Bottom.BorderType = Spire.Doc.Documents.BorderStyle.Single;
footer.Format.Borders.Bottom.Space = 0.06F;
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to insert the same image on each page?